# I created docker image for service using springboot 2.3.0 mvn spring-boot:build-image. it showing age of this image 40 years

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I created docker image for service using new feature in springboot 2.3.0 mvn spring-boot:build-image when check this in docker it showing age of this image 40 years any idea why it so

[image]

Comment: Try this command and please check ```docker inspect -f '{{ .Created }}' IMAGE_NAME_OR_CONTAINER```

Answer (score 1):

This is intentionally done so that if you recreate the build without changing anything, the newly created build is exactly same as the one before.

If the actual timestamp was used, then the two images would have different digest.

Here's a link to spring boot issue that talks about this: [Spring boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20126#issuecomment-585871285)

Comment: it justifies and known, got it